# Error using DBI in perl

Tags: macos, perl, postgresql

I'm unable to use DBI in my current version of perl on my Mac.  When I try to do a simple

```
my $database = "DBI:Pg:dbname=db;host=localhost";
my $db_user = "user";
my $db_pw = "pw";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($database, $db_user, $db_pw, {'RaiseError' => 1});
```

I get the following error:

```
 install_driver(Pg) failed: Can't locate DBD/Pg.pm in @INC 
 Perhaps the DBD::Pg perl module hasn't been fully installed,
 or perhaps the capitalisation of 'Pg' isn't right.
```

I do have two versions of PERL on my machine, but I believe I successfully (using CPAN) installed DBI on the version I am using as a

```
/Applications/apps/bin/perl -e "use DBI"
```

does not return an error.

However, I'm not positive I installed the module using CPA as it ends with this message:

Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
Failed during this command:
 TURNSTEP/DBD-Pg-2.18.1.tar.gz                : make_test NO

Do I need to do something other than a

```
sudo cpan DBD:PG
```

if I have more than one version of Perl on my machine?

UPDATE:  I had a mispelling and should have been doing a sudo CPAN DBI.  I've since done that but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Yes, you need something different. The first thing to try would be to spell the name correctly :-)   sudo cpan DBD::Pg (and if you introduced a typo into your post then shame on you for retyping rather than copy/pasting)

Comment: Wha's the output of (1) `find /usr /Applications -type f -name Pg.pm`, (2) `/Applications/apps/bin/perl /path/to/your/script.pl`?

Comment: The message that you got when you tried to install it with CPAN said that there were errors, and it wouldn't install DBD::Pg.  You need to fix whatever errors that CPAN mentioned when you tried to install DBD::Pg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing here because you do not show the whole output of CPAN with full error messages.

I suspect that the cause is like in the overwhelming majority of cases that you neglected to install the development headers for PostgreSQL.